# How do I use javascript to get & set caret position using character offset?

Tags: javascript

Is there a way to use javascript to get & set caret position using the character offset (relative to the start of the document)?

In my situation, for many reasons, the preferred value to work with is the character offset and not dom nodes. Is there a reasonably fast (no noticeable time) way to accomplish this? I would prefer to treat any 'p' tag as a character ('\n'), but if this makes the solution impossible, ignoring them is ok.

Edit:
Since it is apparently confusing, I am asking about a caret because there is a caret. Not because there isn't. [Those who don't know about contentEditable have no chance of answering the question anyways, so I deemed it unnecessary to explain]. Since I am expected to demonstrate that I tried but don't know the solution to the question I am asking (why else would I be asking, I wonder?), here is the best attempt I have been able to work out. It doesn't give the correct answer.

Edit:
It now gives the correct answer; the only question would be if there is some javascript method or simpler, faster approach.

Edit:
Fixed to give correct answer when selection ends after newline.

```
        function nodeOffset(findnode) {
            var offset = 0;
            var root = document.body
            var node = root.childNodes[0];
            while(node != null) {
                if(node.nodeType == 3) {
                    if(node == findnode)
                        return offset;
                    offset += node.length; //text
                } else if (node.tagName == 'P') {
                    offset += 1; //newline character
                    if(node == findnode)
                        return offset;
                }
                if(node.hasChildNodes()) {
                    node = node.firstChild;
                } else {
                    while(node.nextSibling == null && node != root) {
                        node = node.parentNode;
                    }
                node = node.nextSibling;
                }
            }
        }

        var selection = window.getSelection();
        var offset = nodeOffset(selection.focusNode) + selection.focusOffset;
```

Comment: Mmh, the caret is usually not visible on a page (outside of input elements). So what exactly do you mean?

Comment: When contentEditable is being used, or frankly even when not, and a selection is made, there *is* a caret (and anchor)

Comment: Exactly, that's why I asked for more context. *"or frankly even when not"*, well not for me. If I click anywhere in your post I don't see a caret. The cursor of course changes, if you mean that, but then there would be the question *when* you would want the position. When hovering over a certain element?

Comment: Edit made to clarify. Sorry for inconvenience. In javascript it is also known as 'focus'. It is not the same as cursor position (mouse cursor), but exists even without contentEditable, accessible starting from window.getSelection(). The focus/caret and anchor are the two ends (or even same thing) of any selection/range.

Answer (score 0):

A brute force approach. (It has a good chance of tripping up, for example if other tags are `display:block` or if `p` is not `display:block`, or other possible issues):

To get the selection caret/anchor offset, which may be one and the same:

```
        function nodeOffset(findnode) {
            var offset = 0;
            var root = document.body
            var node = root.childNodes[0];
            while(node != null) {
                if(node.nodeType == 3) {
                    if(node == findnode)
                        return offset;
                    offset += node.length; //text
                } else if (node.tagName == 'P') {
                    offset += 1; //newline character
                    if(node == findnode)
                        return offset;
                }
                if(node.hasChildNodes()) {
                    node = node.firstChild;
                } else {
                    while(node.nextSibling == null && node != root) {
                        node = node.parentNode;
                    }
                node = node.nextSibling;
                }
            }
        }

        var selection = window.getSelection();
        var focusoffset = nodeOffset(selection.focusNode)+selection.focusOffset;
        var anchoroffset = nodeOffset(selection.anchorNode)+selection.anchorOffset;
```

To set the caret/anchor offset, though they must be ordered smallest->largest, with no choice of which to be focus & which to be anchor:

```
        function offsetNode(findoffset) {
            var offset = 0;
            var root = document.body
            var node = root.childNodes[0];
            while(node != null) {
                if(node.nodeType == 3) {
                    offset += node.length; //text
                    if(offset >= findoffset)
                        return [node, findoffset-offset+node.length];
                } else if (node.tagName == 'P') {
                    offset += 1; //newline character
                }
                if(node.hasChildNodes()) {
                    node = node.firstChild;
                } else {
                    while(node.nextSibling == null && node != root) {
                        node = node.parentNode;
                    }
                node = node.nextSibling;
                }
            }
        }

        var selection = window.getSelection();
        var range = document.createRange();
        var start = offsetNode(startoffset)
        var end = offsetNode(endoffset)
        range.setStart(start[0], start[1]);
        range.setEnd(end[0], end[1]);
        selection.removeAllRanges();
        selection.addRange(range);
```